# STL Algorithms using iterator in the target function

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I want to use an function that requires the parameter to be an Iterator, is possible to apply it with an STL algoritm like std::for_each ?

```
std::vector<int> v({0,1,2,3,4});
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](std::vector<int>::iterator it)
{
   // Do something that require using the iterator
   // .....
});
```

Comment: `std::for_each` will pass an object from the container, not iterator. You should use explicit cycle that uses iterators. Make a function (probably template) from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily make your own "implementation" that passes an iterator to the function.

```
namespace custom {
template<class InputIterator, class Function>
  Function for_each(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Function fn)
{
  while (first!=last) {
    fn (first);
    ++first;
  }
  return fn; 
}
}

std::vector<int> v({0,1,2,3,4});
custom::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(),
    [](std::vector<int>::iterator it)
    {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    });
```

I don't see the advantage of this over a simple loop:

```
for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
```

Comment: I like STL Alg style.